# Using SFTP to upload user upload files on a webserver?

Tags: linux, sftp

I looked at a CDN and found i need to use SFTP to upload files to it. Using sftp isnt to difficult but how do i continuously upload files? my webapp current puts apps in /uploads/type/01/02/03/04/05/06/07/08.ext when the file id is 0x0102030405060708

How do i upload these files? do i launch sftp everytime a user uploads a file? is there some kind of deamon mode i can use to monitors when i add something to uploads and uses sftp on it? I was thinking about using cron but i dont want to check if thousands of files exist everytime. Also what happens when the connection has been terminated (lets say i restart my server for maintenance reasons). I dont know whats the easiest way to have everything work.

How

Answer (score 2):

`rsync` is a great tool for synchronizing lots of files with a remote site.

`rsync` runs over ssh so it will work if you have sftp access to your server.  For an automated sync that runs from a cron job, you would setup [ssh public key authentication](http://oreilly.com/pub/h/66) so that the ssh connection does not prompt for a password.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using rdist via a crontab entry?

Comment: I never heard of that. Will it try to sync 100k+ files everytime cron is ran? If it does then its likely not suitable.

Comment: only the ones that are different between the server and the client

Comment: well, thats what i mean. How does it know which are different? it has to check the modified time of 100k+ files right? that would take way to long

Answer (score 0):

What platform does your web application run on?

If it's Linux (or *NIX in general) then `rsync` or `rdist` are good solutions.

If it's a Windows box, then I would recommend you have a loot at synchronization solutions that can observer and keep in sync entire folder trees, like Syncovery (https://www.syncovery.com/) for example, which is my personal favorite. But there's a plethora of options out there, like GoodSync, BestSync, AllWaySync, just to name a few.